# C# Regular Expression : how to extract content from string?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string as below :

```
...[down]&lt;a title="Download: Click Here" href="http://www.domain.com/T60B8JK2WT/" target="_blank"&gt;&lt;strong&gt; blah blah (2011)(1 - 22)&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a title="Download: Click Here" href="http://www.domain.com/5FBLQYBQTV/" target="_blank"&gt;&lt;strong&gt; blah blah (2011) &lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/a&gt;[/down]...
```

How can I find `[down][/down]` tag from string & get all `href` attribute & `text of each link` in [down][/down] tag and put it in a `data table`, with each row of table containing title & url field?

Thanks

Comment: If you try to scrape a piracy website at least sanitize the examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(inputString, 
                                      @"\[down\](?<content>.+)\[/down\]"))
{
    var content = match.Groups["content"].Value;

    var hrefs = new List<string>();

    foreach (Match matchhref in Regex.Matches(t, @"href=""(?<href>[^""]+)"""))
    {
        hrefs.Add(matchhref.Groups["href"].Value);
    }
}
```